# Threading with python, cherrypy and pyserial

Tags: python, arduino, cherrypy, pyserial, python-multithreading

So I coded a web interface to interact with the Arduino Uno, using cherrypy, and pyserial. It's pretty complete, the only thing that I'm missing, and that I've been trying to figure out for a day, is to continuously read the data being sent by the Arduino, and automatically display a div containing the message inside the html code. I can display it in the console, but I can't manage to return actual html. In fact, I can't manage to use return, I have to use print, which is not handy, since I want the data in the html page, not the console.
I have tried many ways to do this.

Here is my code, pretty simple. The constant function keeps reading the data being sent from the Arduino, and sends it to the console. I want it to send it to the html code, like a live update. How do I do this?

```
# -*- coding: Utf-8 -*-

import cherrypy, arduino, time, threading

ser=arduino.Serial('COM4', 9600)

def constant():
    while True:
        m=''
        print('running')
    while True:
        print('sub_running')
        byte=(ser.read().encode('Utf-8'))
        if byte=='*':
            break
        m=m+byte
        time.sleep(1)
    print(m)
    time.sleep(1)

class website(object):
    def index(self):
        return '''
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script><script src="annexes/functions.js"></script>
            <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css media=screen href="/annexes/design.css">
            <form action="command" method="POST">
            <input type="submit" name="command" value="Turn the LED on" text="hey"/>
            <input type="submit" name="command" value="Turn the LED off"/>
            </form>
        '''    
    index.exposed=True

    def command(self, command):
        m=''
        if command=='Turn the LED on':
            ser.write('1')
        if command=='Turn the LED off':
            ser.write('0')
        self.index
    command.exposed=True

_thread = threading.Thread(target=constant)
_thread.setDaemon(True)
_thread.start()

cherrypy.quickstart(website(), config='config.conf')
```

Answer (score 0):

to make it do what you want you got two options:

- make the generated web page prints dynamic data each time you display it, and add a meta refresh (or a javascript refresh) on the client side or
- make a long-polling route that gets updated each time new data comes in (see this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17191744/threading-with-python-cherrypy-and-pyserial))

But I think the core of your question is related on how you can send the values from your thread function to your website class. You'll need to use a [`Queue.Queue`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html):
That examples shows how you can make a long-polling request using cherrypy.

In the following example you'll miss the `jsonyield` decorator that is available on [this site](http://blog.codedstructure.net/2010/12/http-streaming-from-python-generators.html) which is a good read to understand cherrypy and long-polling.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import cherrypy, arduino, time, threading
import Queue

def serialWatcher(ser, queue):
    while True:
        m=''
        print('running')
    while True:
        print('sub_running')
        byte=(ser.read().encode('Utf-8'))
        if byte=='*':
            break
        m=m+byte
        time.sleep(1)
    queue.put(m)
    time.sleep(1)

class website(object):
    def __init__(self, ser, queue):
        self.serial = ser
        self.queue = queue

    # it's often better to use decorators when you can
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return '''
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script><script src="annexes/functions.js"></script>
            <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css media=screen href="/annexes/design.css">
            <form action="command" method="POST">
            <input type="submit" name="command" value="Turn the LED on" text="hey"/>
            <input type="submit" name="command" value="Turn the LED off"/>
            </form>
        '''

    @cherrypy.expose
    def command(self, command):
        m=''
        if command=='Turn the LED on':
            self.serial.write('1')
        if command=='Turn the LED off':
            self.serial.write('0')
        return self.index() # I assume that's what you wanted to write

    @cherrypy.expose
    @json_yield
    def get_arduino_results(self):
        """you can get the result of this long polling request using a JS AJAX query"""
        while True:
            while not self.queue.empty():
                yield self.queue.get()


# always use the following, so you can also use the module you're writing as imports
# in other modules
if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = Queue.Queue()
    # Never use global variables, always pass them as parameters
    ser = arduino.Serial('COM4', 9600) 

    _thread = threading.Thread(target=serialWatcher, args=(ser, q))
    _thread.setDaemon(True)
    _thread.start()

    cherrypy.quickstart(website(ser, q), config='config.conf')

but the same principle would work for a standard page, something like:

    @cherrypy.expose
    get_arduino_results(self):
        out = "<ul>"
        while not self.queue.empty():
            out += "<li>" + self.queue.get() + "</li>"
        return out + "</ul>
```

The whole idea of using a `Queue` is that you won't risk having threading issues while exchanging information between your arduino watching thread and the cherrypy thread. The Queue is thread safe, and synchronizes read/writes so they happen ordered, and one thread at a time.

HTH

Comment: Hey thank you very much for your great answer, but I can't seem to figure out how to "install" the jsonyield decorator that I just downloaded. How is that?

Comment: well you can put the code you downloaded in the same directory as your code in a file called `jsonyield.py` and at the beginning of your code you can do `from jsonyield import jsonyield`. Another (ugly) solution is to copy paste the whole `jsonyield` function at the top of your source file (but don't forget the imports it needs too!)

Comment: Thanks very much, so your solution is supposed to live display what is being sent by the arduino right? When I click on a button, nothing visibly happens. My arduino is looping the same thing on its side: every 2 seconds, it sends a different message. So the script is supposed to live update the webpage isn't it?

Comment: So far I'm just trying to analyze and understand your code to create a web app that will update the page everytime it gets data from the arduino. Then I'll try to implement it to this module. What's the minimum code that will just live update a webpage with arduino data?

Comment: the first solution (using longpolling and jsonyield) will return every updates each time you call the `get_arduino_results` method. So in your javascript code, if you want to have all events since you loaded the page, you'll have to store those events in an array, and update the array using your AJAX call. The other method I'm suggesting will only return all events that has been queued since last call. So, if you want to always show all events that way, you should find another structure.

Comment: the javascript code is as an example on [the website](http://blog.codedstructure.net/2010/12/http-streaming-from-python-generators.html) I've given you. But, I've never used cherrypy myself (I prefer bottle.py), so I never tried to implement what you're trying to do. But if the tutorial is right, it should head you towards what you want.